# High charts bar chart label overlaps with the graph when labels are long

Tags: highcharts, label, zk

I need the xAxis label to have a tool tip. But when I use a formatter to add the tool tip , then long labels tend to overlap with the chart instead of pushing it to the right. Also this only happens if the label has a white space , if white spaces are removed then it work properly and pushes the chart to the right. This problem is shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W5wag/44

```
$(function(){
    var chart1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasadadadad adadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'],
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<span title="abc">' + this.value + '</span>';
                },
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
            }
        },
      },

    };

    options.series = [{
            data: [3, 4, 4, 3, 9]
        }];
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
})
```

Comment: When you disable useHTML option the chart is pushed to the right and the title works as well http://jsfiddle.net/W5wag/46/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute some code after the labels have been rendered, but my experience is a bit limited there. I'd try to find the maximum width of any of the x-axis labels, set that as the min-width of the parent (as below), and invalidate the labels to trigger a redraw. Maybe you can find a way to do that.

If all else fails, you could "cheat" with these quick-n-dirty solutions:

Set the text without spaces, and add them afterwards, when the layout is done.

```
 window.setTimeout(()=>document.querySelector('span[title=abc]')
                     .innerHTML='cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasadadad adadadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 500);
```

Or, add css to the page (which requires knowing how wide the labels will be, though):

```
.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels > * { min-width: XXXpx }
```